# Negation of a statement? Confused

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

My book wants me to give the negation of the defining statement below

“A set of Real Numbers S has the Archimedian property iff

∀ a, b ∈ S, ∃ n ∈ N such that na > b”

Now, I know logically in general the negation of x>y would be x ≤ y

However, it seems to me that here the negation should be

“∃ a, b ∈ S such that ∀ n ∈ N, na = b” as opposed to “∃ a, b ∈ S such that ∀ n ∈ N, na ≤ b”

Because, if na < b then that implies bn > a for n = 1, which would mean it does the fit the original defition.

SIDE NOTE: If I’m understanding this property correctly, does any set S of real numbers have the archimedian property iff S = ø and 0 ∉ S.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You want the negation of $na>b$.

This cannot be $na=b$, because there are cases where both $na>b$ and $na=b$ are false, for example if $n=a=b=2$.

Even in the context *with* the quantifiers, your proposed negation does not mean the opposite of the original statement. For example, your proposed negation is not satisfied by $S=\{-1,1\}$, even though that set also fails to satisfy the original definition that it's supposed to be a negation of.

In general, when you negate a statement, you should not be thinking about *implications* -- just about *getting the opposite truth value* in every situation.

Answer (score 0):

No. What you do here may work for $n=1$, but note that the statement is about *any* $n$.

Also, as a piece of advice for future work, when you are asked to provide a logical negation, you should just work with that. Yes, given some intended interpretation, you can sometimes write it as a different statement (e.g if the domain is natural numbers, we can use $x=0$ instead of $x <1$, but *logically* those two statements are not equivalent.

Comment: So I understand everything you said regarding implications, however if we find for two arbitrary elements that bn > a, isn't that functionally the same as an > b as far as the definition is concerned? Since we could have just picked a to be b, and b to be a.

Comment: @StrugglingMathStudent Oh, I see what you mean. Well, then please note that what you say works for $n=1$, but not for all $n$ ... and the resulting statement is about $\forall n$,